# Strange keyboard layout after running my app

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently I'm developing android app uses Camera, SurfaceView, GMaps, GPS and fullscreen mode without ability to rotation.

What I'm surprised about is that sometimes after starting my app I see corrupted layout for cifiral keyboard of my HTC Desire phone.

Here is a screen:

[image: smth strange]

And this is how it have to be if OK:

[image]

Could you please explain what is the reason of this strange phone behavior?